# How to assign colours for the data from text file so that the background cell of the data have different colors?

Tags: php, flat-file

[Image of the table created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzL3Q.png) 
I want data to have different colour background cells. How to assign colours for the data so that the background cell of the data have different colours

This is the content of the text file

```
Date/Days   | MON    | TUE    | WED    | THU    |FRI
08am - 10am |        | STA416 |        | MAT421 | 
10am - 12pm | ITT400 | CSC404 | CTU554 | STA416 | CSC404 
12pm - 02pm |        |        |        |        |  
02pm - 04pm | MAT421 | CSC404 | ITT400 |        |
04pm - 06pm |        |        |        |        |
```

This is how I read my text file data into the table.

```
<?php
$myfile = "C:/xampp\htdocs\dashboard\FYP2\SCHEDULE\PART2.txt";
$content = file($myfile);
echo '<table id="table_id">';
$file = fopen($myfile, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($file)) {
  $data = fgets($file);
  echo "<tr><td style='background-color: plum;'>" . str_replace('|', '</td><td>', $data) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random "light" color like so:

```
$min = 200;
$max - 255;
$color = rand($min, $max).', '.rand($min, $max).', '.rand($min, $max);

echo "<tr><td style='background-color: rgb(" . $color . ");'>" . str_replace('|','</td><td>',$data) . '</td></tr>'; }
```

If you can add a color to the text file then you could use that in the resulting table.

```
Date/Days   | MON    | TUE    | WED    | THU    |FRI      | Color
08am - 10am |        | STA416 |        | MAT421 |         | red
10am - 12pm | ITT400 | CSC404 | CTU554 | STA416 | CSC404  | #ff0034
12pm - 02pm |        |        |        |        |         | rgb(200,200,100)
02pm - 04pm | MAT421 | CSC404 | ITT400 |        |         | green
04pm - 06pm |        |        |        |        |         | blue
```

```
  $data = fgets($file);
  $cells = array_map('trim', explode('|', $data));
  $color = array_pop($cells);
  $row = implode('</td><td>', $cells);
  echo "<tr><td style='background-color: ".$color.";'>" . $row . '</td></tr>';
```

I'm not sure how else to answer this.